# Why /lib/ld-linux.so.2 soname version bumps are so rare?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, glibc

As far as I understand, "2" in "/lib/ld-linux.so.2" changes very rarely. There are old programs that can't work with new library and new programs that can't work with the old library. But they both refer to /lib/ld-linux.so.2, preventing installing both libraries.

BTW what are that `version 'GLIBC_2.17' not found` things? Why version is not in soname, but somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a library is changed in a way that old programs do not work with the new version of the library this number is chaned. If old programs will still work with the newer library (and programs needing the new version will not cause a crash with the old library) there is no need to change the number because you can simply install the latest version of the library.

As far as I understand the "2" (it was "1" ten years ago) should not change any longer. The reason is simple:

The first version of "ld-linux.so.2" was written in a way that any version of "ld-linux.so.2" should work with any program using this file - maybe printing an error message when an older version of "ld-linux.so.2" is used.

This means: It is never necessary to install two different "ld-linux.so.2" files but it is enough to install the latest version of this file. You should not simply overwrite this file because it comes as a bundle with other files (e.g. "libc.so.6") that must have the *same* version.

In the "2" version of the loader .so files may contain a table of version numbers supported. So "libc.so.6", version GLIBC_2.16, may contain the information that "GLIBC_2.15" is also supported by this version of the library. (New versions should be backward compatible so this should be the case.)

Programs may contain a list of versions required (for example: a program requires libc.so.6 version "GLIBC_2.17"). The loader (ld-linux.so.2) checks if the library supports the version that is required by the program and refuses starting the program if not. In this case the error message form your question is printed by the loader.